# Viewer for multiple batch scripts

Tags: windows, windows-10, scripting, shell-scripting, batch

I have 12 batch (.bat) scripts which have to automatically start when Windows boots. Most of them are endless-running.

To accomplish that, I added a bat file in `shell:startup`, which looks like this example:

```
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"C:\bla\bla\bla\batch script 1.bat"
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"C:\bla\bla\bla\batch script 2.bat"
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"C:\bla\bla\bla\batch script 3.bat"
vdesk on:2 noswitch:true run:"C:\bla\bla\bla\batch script 4.bat"
```

I use [vdesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk) to start all the cmd windows on the second virtual desktop, so they don't annoy me while I work.

**But this seems to be a bit unprofessional, I wonder if there is a program which can do this better: Autostarting, managing and showing a lot of batch scripts in a single window. I would like to see all scripts at once (Or maybe 9, in a "table" with 3 columns and 3 rows, the others in another tab). Additionally I would like to easily start scripts from some kind of a dropdown menu, stop scripts and restart scripts.**

Please note that running the scripts as a Windows service or something similar is not a solution for me because sometimes I have to look what the scripts are doing. They can throw errors or do things they shouldn't do.

Comment: Wow, this is already much better that what I do. Didn't know about vdesk until now.